# Duplicate Symbols causing Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am receiving the following error when building my project.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_PrintAdventureMenuViewController in:
/Users/ethanraymond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jake-and-bailey-fbutnsfforlfnpgkxyojdsdcaobc/Build/Intermediates/jake-and-bailey.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jake-and-bailey.build/Objects-normal/i386/PrintAdventureMenuViewController.o
/Users/ethanraymond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jake-and-bailey-fbutnsfforlfnpgkxyojdsdcaobc/Build/Intermediates/jake-and-bailey.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jake-and-bailey.build/Objects-normal/i386/AdventureTypeMenuViewController.o

duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PrintAdventureMenuViewController in:
/Users/ethanraymond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jake-and-bailey-fbutnsfforlfnpgkxyojdsdcaobc/Build/Intermediates/jake-and-bailey.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jake-and-bailey.build/Objects-normal/i386/PrintAdventureMenuViewController.o
/Users/ethanraymond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jake-and-bailey-fbutnsfforlfnpgkxyojdsdcaobc/Build/Intermediates/jake-and-bailey.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jake-and-bailey.build/Objects-normal/i386/AdventureTypeMenuViewController.o

ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This was just after creating "PrintAdventureMenuViewController" class. So it is currently empty. "AdventureTypeMenuViewController" is not empty. It is populated with views other code.

Comment: Try to delete derived folder in libaray class in finder and re build again. If error till occurs then check is there any same naming variable declare in both class

Comment: Neither of those worked unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that in the AdventureTypeMenuViewController.m file I used the import statement...

```
#import "PrintAdventureMenuViewController.m"
```

rather than...

```
#import "PrintAdventureMenuViewController.h"
```